# Can I debug Windows Store applications on a non Microsoft tablet?

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I am about to create a Windows Store application, and need to purchase a Windows RT device for testing. Is the Microsoft Surface the only device that supports remote debugging from Visual Studio? Or will it also work with a third party tablet from for example Samsung?

Comment: I would say, with 99.9% certainty, that you can without any problems debug with a non surface device. Like you don't need a Nokia windows phone to test a windows phone application.

Comment: I'll make it 100% certainty.  :)  You don't need a Surface; this works with any Windows RT device.

Answer (score 2):

For debugging on a tablet you need to install the Remote Debugging tools on the tablet. Secondly, both machine (your developer rig and the tablet) need to be on the same net and the local firewalls must allow access. Then you choose Remote Debugging in VS2012 and you can choose the tablet. On a Surface RT I had to enter the name manually, as it has not found it by searching the local network.

Tim Heuer has a blog entry exactly about this topic: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/10/26/remote-debugging-windows-store-apps-on-surface-arm-devices.aspx At the very end he says:

> Now that you have a Surface (or other Windows RT device)

If your tablet is x86 it is a PC and is able to run the remote debugging agent, too. Note: download the correct version (x86, x64 or ARM)